# how to merge two or more sql for xml path curusor statemenets

Tags: sql, xml

I have these two separate pieces of coding, each delivering information their receptive information:

```
select
(
    select cast(
        (CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),date,113))
        + ' - Attenance with ' 
        + (select cast((select name from feeearner where id=ptFeeEarner) as varchar(max))) 
        + ' at our offices' 
    as Varchar(max))
    + char(10) 

    from workinprogress 
    where ptmatter=$matter$ 
    and ((ptActivity=91) or (ptActivity=93) or (ptActivity=95) or (ptActivity=117) or (ptActivity=119) or (ptActivity=121) or (ptActivity=128)) 
    GROUP BY date,ptFeeEarner 
    for xml path (''), type
)
```

> 10 Mar 2011 - Attendance  with Linda
>   Parish at our offices
>
> 17 Mar 2011 - Attendance  with Linda
>   Parish at our offices
>
> 13 Apr 2011 - Attendance  with Linda
>   Parish at our offices
>
> 04 May 2011 - Attendance  with Linda
>   Parish at our offices

```
select
(
    select cast(
        (CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),date,113)) 
        + ' - Court Attendance by ' 
        + (select cast((select name from feeearner where id=ptFeeEarner) as varchar(max))) 
    as Varchar(max))
    + char(10) 

    from workinprogress 
    where ptmatter=$matter$ 
    and ((ptActivity=96) or (ptActivity=112) or (ptActivity=130) or (ptActivity=132) or (ptActivity between 163 and 246) or (ptActivity between 256 and 261)) 
    GROUP BY date,ptFeeEarner for xml path (''), type
)
```

> 01 Mar 2011 - Court Attendance by
>   Linda Parish
>
> 13 Apr 2011 - Court Attendance by
>   Linda Parish
>
> 03 May 2011 - Court Attendance by
>   Linda Parish
>
> 13 May 2011 - Court Attendance by
>   Linda Parish

However, I would like to merge the two pieces of code into one, thus delivering (including a line break between the two result sets) :-

> 10 Mar 2011 - Attendance  with Linda
>   Parish at our offices
>
> 17 Mar 2011 - Attendance  with Linda
>   Parish at our offices
>
> 13 Apr 2011 - Attendance  with Linda
>   Parish at our offices
>
> 04 May 2011 - Attendance  with Linda
>   Parish at our offices
>
> 01 Mar 2011 - Court Attendance by
>   Linda Parish
>
> 13 Apr 2011 - Court Attendance by
>   Linda Parish
>
> 03 May 2011 - Court Attendance by
>   Linda Parish
>
> 13 May 2011 - Court Attendance by
>   Linda Parish

additionally, is there a way of shortening the lists of ptAcivity values?

thanks

james

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the list by doing your query like:

```
ptactivity in (96,112,130,132) or ptactivity between 163 and 246 or ptactivity between 256 and 261)
```

I don't see why a union wouldn't work but i've not tested it.